# How to "remove" WordPress categories UL and make the list loop in a horizontal line?

Tags: categories, css

When you list categories in WordPress they are looped via an array using a standard manner like this:

```
             <ul>
               <li>catgory1</li>
             </ul>
```

In fact, the class in question is `<ul class="post-categories">` can anyone think of a way to remove these and make them display horizontally so that they are like this:

apples, pears, bananas, peaches etc?

One solution is to mess about with the core files but that's never a good idea right?

Comment: In what context? How and where are you listing categories? And are you listing all categories or just categories assigned to a post?

Comment: Why don’t you just use CSS to display the list in the way you like? Semantically it still is a list, right?